# Dagger 2 dynamic injection when button gets clicked

Tags: android, dagger-2

Not sure if it is possible or not. However, I am looking for a way to solve this.

```
class User(val name: String, val email: String)

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject lateinit var vm: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
        DaggerMyActivityComponent.create().inject(this)
        super.onCreate(bundle)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my)

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            vm.insert(pathEditText.text.toString(), User("test name", "test email"))
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(val repo: MyRepository) {
    fun insert(path: String, user: User) {
        repo.insert(user)
    }
}

class MyRepository(path: String) {
    val collection = Firebase.firestore.collection(path)

    fun insert(user: User) {
        collection.set(user)
    }
}

@Component(modules = [MyModule::class])
interface MyActivityComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MyActivity)
}

@Module class MyModule {
    @Provides fun repo() = MyRepository(How do I get the path here?)
}
```

**Question:**

How do I get the path being injected into MyModule's @Provides fun repo() dynamically since the path can only be known when user types the EditText.

I am not sure if it is possible or not. However, would love to know a possible solution. I am even ready to change my overall solution if it fits my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [flyweight factory](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight) to create new repo instances. Like this:

```
class MyRepositoryFactory {

  fun create(path: String): MyRepository {
    return MyRepository(path)
  }

}

@Module class MyModule {
    @Provides fun repoFactory() = MyRepositoryFactory()
}

class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(val repoFactory: MyRepositoryFactory) {
    fun insert(path: String, user: User) {
        repoFactory.create(path).insert(user)
    }
}
```